# Difference between Content Protection and DRM

Tags: drm

In this recent post about criticism regarding built-in [DRM in Intels SandyBridge processors](http://blogs.intel.com/technology/2011/01/intel_insider_-_what_is_it_no.php?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+TechnologyIntel+(Technology%40Intel)), Intel denies that there's any DRM in Sandybridge processors but goes on to say that

> Intel created Intel insider, an extra layer of content protection. Think of it as an armoured truck carrying the movie from the Internet to your display, it keeps the data safe from pirates, but still lets you enjoy your legally acquired movie in the best possible quality

I'm confused now. So far I was thinking DRM is content protection. Can someone shed light on this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**DRM = Content Protection**.

No matter what spin they put on it, that is most definitely DRM.

Taken from [here](http://www.techterms.com/definition/drm):

> DRM refers to a collection of systems used to protect the copyrights of electronic media. These include digital music and movies, as well as other data that is stored and transferred digitally.

Comment: Well ... very technically ... content protection refers to the property that there is some assurance that what was sent from one end of the wire is what will come out the other end of the wire.  SSL, for example, is a form of "content protection" which assures to some extent that no one "in the middle" has tampered with the content.  DRM uses content protection (in addition to other things) to try to assure the producer that you, the consumer, have not tampered with the content.